# Why does ThreadPoolExecutor in concurrent.futures take longer to run than non-parallelised?

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor, concurrent.futures

I have a parallelised program using *concurrent.futures/ThreadPoolExecutor*:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as PoolExecutor
import numpy as np, timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
n = 2

def f(samp):
    t = samp ** 10
        
samps = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(100000,))

with PoolExecutor(max_workers=n) as executor:
    for _ in executor.map(f, samps):
        pass

print(f"time: {timeit.default_timer() - start}")
```

It takes about 3s to run.

If I run it sequentially without parallelising, i.e.:

```
for samp in samps: t = samp ** 10
```

It takes about 0.05s to run (i.e. 100,000 iterations).

Why is the parallelised version taking so much longer. NB increasing *max_workers* also increases run time. Also, this maybe a silly code example but my original code was processing 800 files - it also took longer than the sequential version.

Comment: My guess would be the time taken by the parallel version is dominated not by the actual work done in the threads, but by the spawning of those threads themselves. Each thread needs to be passed something from the `samps` array - this happends sequentially & that takes time. If you decrease the size fo `samps` I'd wager the runtime for the parallel version also goes down.

Comment: @rdas OK thanks, if I give it something more difficult such as multiplying arrays I start to see some benefit - still puzzled why my file processing wasn't improved but don't know how to post the data for others to view/analyse

Comment: Math is a work for CPU (speed and/or cache size matter). Python threads can't help in this case due to GIL. You should use multiple processes for CPU bound operations (math) and multiple threads for I/O bound operations (data transfer).